# Flutter, external DLL and Pointer<Char> vs Pointer<Utf8>

Tags: flutter, dart, dll, ffi

I try to call the tesseract C api within flutter. So far without success. The function "TessBaseAPIInit3" requires the 2nd and 3rd parameter to be of type `Pointer<Char>`. The following is what `dart run ffigen` generated out of tesseract's capi.h:

```
    import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;

    ...

    int TessBaseAPIInit3(
    ffi.Pointer<TessBaseAPI> handle,
    ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> datapath,
    ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> language,
  ) {
    return _TessBaseAPIInit3(
      handle,
      datapath,
      language,
    );
  }

  late final _TessBaseAPIInit3Ptr = _lookup<
      ffi.NativeFunction<
          ffi.Int Function(ffi.Pointer<TessBaseAPI>, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char>,
              ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char>)>>('TessBaseAPIInit3');
  late final _TessBaseAPIInit3 = _TessBaseAPIInit3Ptr.asFunction<
      int Function(ffi.Pointer<TessBaseAPI>, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char>,
          ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char>)>();
```

The following is my code which calls `TessBaseAPIInit3` which requires 3 parameters of type `Pointer<TessBaseAPI>, Pointer<Char>, Pointer<Char>`. The string literals i create with `toNativeUtf8` have type `Pointer<Utf8>` which i cast to `Pointer<Char>` in the hope that they are equivalent. But the cast from `Pointer<Utf8>` to `Pointer<Char>` gives an error.

```
  import 'dart:ffi';

  ...

  final DynamicLibrary tesseractDLL = DynamicLibrary.open(Platform.script.resolve("build/windows/runner/Debug/libtesseract-5.dll").toFilePath());
  NativeLibrary tesseractLib = NativeLibrary(tesseractDLL);

  final handle = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPICreate();
  final Pointer<Char> dataPath = ''.toNativeUtf8() as Pointer<Char>;
  final Pointer<Char> language = 'eng'.toNativeUtf8() as Pointer<Char>;

  if (tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIInit3(handle, dataPath, language) != 0)
    print("Error initializing tesseract\n");
```

The error message is: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Pointer<Utf8>' is not a subtype of type 'Pointer<Char>' in type cast`

Any ideas what goes wrong? I have no idea how to create a string literal of type `Pointer<Char>`. The function 'toNativeUtf8' generates `Pointer<Utf8>`.

Is this "the right way" to call tesseract functions? Is it possible to use the c++ api anyhow? I don't want to use any wrapper, i would like to interact with the tesseract api directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following did the trick. The native utf8 string needed to be cast to Char.

```
  final dataPath = ''.toNativeUtf8().cast<Char>();
  final language = 'eng'.toNativeUtf8().cast<Char>();
```